# Stackoverflowerror while using distinct in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-2.0

I use Spark **2.0.1**.

I am trying to find distinct values in a JavaRDD as below

```
JavaRDD<String> distinct_installedApp_Ids = filteredInstalledApp_Ids.distinct();
```

I see that this line is throwing the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.checkpointRDD(RDD.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPartitions(UnionRDD.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:84)
   ..........
```

The same stacktrace is repeated again and again.
The input filteredInstalledApp_Ids has large input with millions of records.Will thh issue be the number of records or is there a efficient way to find distinct values in JavaRDD. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Edit 1:

Adding the filter method

```
JavaRDD<String> filteredInstalledApp_Ids = installedApp_Ids
        .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        @Override
          public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
                return v1 != null;
            }
          }).cache();
```

Edit 2:

Added the method used to generate installedApp_Ids

```
 public JavaRDD<String> getIdsWithInstalledApps(String inputPath, JavaSparkContext sc,
        JavaRDD<String> installedApp_Ids) {

    JavaRDD<String> appIdsRDD = sc.textFile(inputPath);
    try {
        JavaRDD<String> appIdsRDD1 = appIdsRDD.map(new Function<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(String t) throws Exception {
                String delimiter = "\t";
                String[] id_Type = t.split(delimiter);
                StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(id_Type[1]);
                if ((temp.indexOf("\"")) != -1) {
                    String escaped = temp.toString().replace("\\", "");
                    escaped = escaped.replace("\"{", "{");
                    escaped = escaped.replace("}\"", "}");
                    temp = new StringBuilder(escaped);
                }
                // To remove empty character in the beginning of a
                // string
                JSONObject wholeventObj = new JSONObject(temp.toString());
                JSONObject eventJsonObj = wholeventObj.getJSONObject("eventData");
                int appType = eventJsonObj.getInt("appType");
                if (appType == 1) {
                    try {                           
                        return (String.valueOf(appType));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }).cache();
        if (installedApp_Ids != null)
            return sc.union(installedApp_Ids, appIdsRDD1);
        else
            return appIdsRDD1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `distinct` given it's a transformation? How do you create `filteredInstalledApp_Ids`? What action do you execute?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I have added the filter method I am using to create filteredInstalledApp_Ids. Basically I am trying to filter null values from the original RDD

Comment: Why RDDs? Why Java? What's the Spark version?

Comment: I am comfortable with java. So I am using java. Spark version 2.0.1.

Why RDDs?
I ll be happy to use if any other provisions are available. Thanks for your prompt reply. Cheers

Comment: Can you show a sample of the content of `inputPath`? I can't guess how `appType` looks like and how the JSON it's in looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the main dataset is in `inputPath`. It *appears* that it's a comma-separated file with JSON-encoded values.

I think you could make your code a bit simpler by combination of Spark SQL's DataFrames and `from_json` function. I'm using Scala and leave converting the code to Java as a home exercise :)

The lines where you load a `inputPath` text file and the line parsing itself can be as simple as the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark: SparkSession = ...
val dataset = spark.read.csv(inputPath)
```

You can display the content using `show` operator.

```
dataset.show(truncate = false)
```

You should see the JSON-encoded lines.

It *appears* that the JSON lines contain `eventData` and `appType` fields.

```
val jsons = dataset.withColumn("asJson", from_json(...))
```

See [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object for reference.

With JSON lines, you can select the fields of your interest:

```
val apptypes = jsons.select("eventData.appType")
```

And then `union` it with `installedApp_Ids`.

I'm sure the code gets easier to read (and hopefully to write too). The migration will give you extra optimizations that you may or may not be able to write yourself using assembler-like RDD API.

And the best is that filtering out nulls is as simple as using `na` operator that gives [DataFrameNaFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) like `drop`. I'm sure you'll like them.

---

It does not necessarily answer your initial question, but this `java.lang.StackOverflowError` might get away just by doing the code migration and the code gets easier to maintain, too.

Comment: Let me try scala and see if the issue gets resolved. Thanks